# What are Streams used for?

Tags: php, stream

http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php

Lots of functions, and possibly, lots of appliances. But, what, for example, I would want to use streams for? And what are they used for in general?

Comment: you are likely using streams already without knowing, for instance when use `file_get_contents` with a url

Comment: RTFM? This page, and it's link will probably explain it all http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php

Comment: I read the pages regarding Streams, but I still think that the potential power that can be harnessed with Streams resides in shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stream is a generalization of basically any I/O (input, output) or even more generally anything that can be read from or written to. If you've ever opened a file with `fopen` you've used a stream. If you've ever downloaded a remote file using `file_get_contents('http://exmaple.com')`, you've used a stream. There are Stream Wrappers for `http://`, simple local files, `zip://` and many more. Functions like `fopen` and `file_get_contents` are rather high-level, all the functions listed in the manual you link to are even lower level and, for example, allow you to pipe data from one stream directly into another, e.g. direct file-to-file data copy, and other nice things you can do with I/O operations on a rather low level

Comment: Could I possibly use streams to expose PHP application API to other languages?

Comment: Streams are a PHP concept. You may be able to use them somewhere in an API, but no, not really. You could make a stream *socket* which listens to incoming data and returns data. But that's a standard socket interface and has nothing much to do with streams in particular.